# SQL Running Total Using Two Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sample dataset

| ID | Type | Opening Balance | Trans Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Credit | 1000.00 | 40.00 |
| 2 | Debit | 1000.00 | -50.00 |
| 3 | Debit | 1000.00 | -20.00 |
| 4 | Credit | 1000.00 | 10.00 |
| 5 | Debit | 1000.00 | -30.00 |

The opening balance is a fixed amount from the previous day. What i want is to use it to start computing the running balance from the first row. The desired output should be as follows

| ID | Type | Opening Balance | Trans Amount | Running Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Credit | 1000.00 | 40.00 | 1040.00 |
| 2 | Debit | 1000.00 | -50.00 | 990.00 |
| 3 | Debit | 1000.00 | -20.00 | 970.00 |
| 4 | Credit | 1000.00 | 10.00 | 980.00 |
| 5 | Debit | 1000.00 | -30.00 | 950.00 |

The script i have written so far is only able to do a running total on the trans amount without factoring the opening balance on the first row

```
    SELECT SUM([trans amount]) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) from dbo.table1
```

How do i achieve the intended results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was originally going the same direction as lemon's answer, but figured a way that you only add `[Opening Balance]` from the first row would be useful as well.

You can make a CTE with a `case` that will add the first row to get your new total, and then the rest of the original values, and then sum that new column:

```
with tbl as
(
    select ID
        , Type
        , [Opening Balance]
        , [Trans Amount]
        , case
            when ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) = 1 then [Opening Balance] + sum([Trans Amount]) over (order by ID)
            else [Trans Amount]
          end [New Trans Amount]
    from orig_tbl
)
select ID
    , Type
    , [Opening Balance]
    , sum([New Trans Amount]) over (order by ID) [Running Total]
from tbl
```

What's nice about this way is that your subsequent opening balance can vary without affecting `[Running Total]`.

[image: example]

However, if `[Opening Balance]` does not vary, then lemon's version is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to add up the *Opening Balance* value to your window function result:

```
SELECT *,
       [Opening Balance] + SUM([Trans Amount]) OVER(ORDER BY [ID]) AS [Running Total]
FROM table1
```

Partitioning inside the window function is not necessary as long as you have unique values for the *ID* field (at least in the input sample).

Try it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4fbb0ac0a3a1fcf3351798c31ebcf4c8).

Note: I have assumed you're using SQL Server by looking at your query. If that's not the case, please indicate it into your post as a tag.